# Can the Ratchet and Clank "Burn Ring" Appear in other games?

Tags: technical-issues, hardware, ratchet-and-clank

There's a cheat/glitch in the first Ratchet and Clank game where you can glitch onto one of the race tracks whilst on foot. Positioning yourself under a bunch of crates (so they're off screen) and using the [Taunter](http://ratchet.wikia.com/wiki/Taunter) (a soundwave weapon) in their direction, allows you to break the crates for bolts. The crates, being off-screen, instantly re-spawn on the race track, allowing the players to continue to break them and receive the bolts. This allows you to buy the more expensive items such as the R.Y.N.O, as well as the Gold Weapon upgrades.

The drawback is that doing this for too long is that it can "burn" this ring into the disk which can make the game unstable or even unreadable.

What's the likelihood of something similar to happen in other games? The glitch in Ratchet and Clank was fixed up in PAL copies and the HD Re-Release would have that fix but I'm more thinking in terms of something like:

**Example 1:**

> In an RPG, being back and forwards in a small location to get random encounters to grind exp, even going so far as to have a controller or macro repeatedly press the confirm button so just the basic move is performed

**Example 2:**

> Having the game in a pause screen or menu where the game is effectively paused

Comment: it was called the taunter, and the feat is still possible by glitching yourself through a wall with the decoy glove

Comment: @ratchetfreak is that for the HD version, if so then it seems like Ratchet and Clank can be used to milk money from idiots who want to get the Rhino and upgrade half their guns in the first playthrough

Comment: @ratchetfreak & Memor-X - I can confirm the Decoy Glove glitch still works on the PS3 HD rerelease. What was the Hologuise one? I'm in a PAL region so I never found this one.

Comment: @Robotnik if you wore the hologuise when joining the blackwater city race you could walk around the track instead of having to race.

Comment: @ratchetfreak - Ah cool, thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a way to damage a disc by playing the same part of the game over and over again.  The power output of the laser is not sufficient to damage commercially printed discs in any reasonable time frame.  The motor that moves the laser will likely fail before the disc or any of the other components will.

It's also not true that playing a particular part of the game is more likely to read from the same locations on the disc repeatedly than playing the game normally.  The game data could be laid out on the disc in such a way that certain portions of the disc see more usage if you're playing normally rather than playing in a particular area.  For instance, during a portion of the game where you're standing still, the game might not need to access the disc much at all.  On the other hand, loading your game and playing through several levels might cause a much higher load on the disc.

You may be thinking of [screen burn-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in) instead - if you leave a game running and the display on, over time the image can become permanently visible in the display, even when the game is off.  Depending on the display technology, this may take more or less time.  Many games have static status bars or other UI elements that encourage this form of burn-in.

Comment: I might add that most modern games probably don't rely on ROM disk access nearly as much as they used to.  Once content is in memory, you can access it over and over with no effect on the disk, and it is efficient to do so.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlxq0TF3sqU at about 4:45 is the place where the Ratch and Clank Cheat i was talking about is done, if you have a one of those rapid fire controllers you can leave it for house and continue to rake in bolts. i think the disk is still loading as the box's destroyed only remain destroyed if you finish the race which means they respawn, i can't remember the sites exactly but they did warn about this burn ring if you did this cheat

Comment: @EBongo the example i gave was from a PS2, it's probably good to know that modern games are a bit more protected

Comment: @Memor-X, there is no way to "burn" a disc in the way you describe, regardless of method, technology, etc.  If you've got a disc that is exhibiting a problem after hours/days/weeks of play, I'd suggest contacting customer support.  Most discs fail due to poor handling (ie, scratches).  Discs burned in CD/DVD recorders have a higher failure rate, but commercially produced discs will outlast the players if they're properly cared for.

Comment: @agent86 hmmm, it could be the warning was targeting bootleg copies of the game, considering how long it took me to get the game from ebay i never tried to risk it

Comment: @Memor-X, the whole thing sounds kinda like an urban legend to me.  Pics or it didn't happen ;)  Early Xbox 360 units could scratch discs (due to poor disc tray design) but I've never heard of a disc failing due to overuse.  If it was possible, it seems like DVDs would fail a lot more often - think of the infinitely looping menu animations those things do.